# How to speed up iterating through a massive (5GB) .json.gz file in Python?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, loops

I have this huge .json.gz file that I'm opening with gzip and trying to iterate through. This file is too large to work with for my purposes (recommender system) so I'm trying to reduce the data while saving it in a dataframe (.parquet) as well.

I have a counter on my code so I can see the progress I'm making. There’s over 15 million rows in this file and after 30 minutes it only gets up to 350,000 rows, meaning it'll take 20 hours to iterate through the whole thing!

```
n_review=0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['user_id', 'book_id', 'rating'])

with gzip.open('goodreads_reviews_dedup.json.gz') as fin:
        for l in fin:
            d = ujson.loads(l)
            df.loc[n_review] = [d['user_id'],d['book_id'],d['rating']]
            
            #counter to check progress
            if n_review % 1000 == 0:
                print(n_review, end=',')
            n_review += 1
```

Is there better code for my purposes? or a way to speed it up?

I've tried using ultrajson in order to speed up the file reading, but that didn't help much. I also tried google colab and it went super fast for about 15 seconds, then it stared going slower than my local notebook, and it does this consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a generator to get values for three columns for each line instead of adding to dataframe each iteration (which can be costly):

```py
def get_data(file_name):
    with gzip.open(file_name) as fin:
        for l in fin:
            d = ujson.loads(l)
            yield d['user_id'], d['book_id'], d['rating']

df = pd.DataFrame(get_data('goodreads_reviews_dedup.json.gz'), columns = ['user_id', 'book_id', 'rating'])
```